# ¿Cómo comparar cada uno de los elementos de una lista con ellos mismos?

Tags: python, django, lista, django-views

Tengo una lista en Python

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Quiero recorrer la anterior lista , pero en cada iteración comparar esa iteración con todos los demás elementos de la misma lista (incluyendo al valor de la iteración actual) para realizar una consulta a la base de datos y verificar si existe un valor , de lo contrario regresaría cero (0)

suponiendo que estamos iterando en la lista: para la primera iteración que es el **1** ahí se debe iterar de nuevo todos los elementos de la misma lista para realizar unas comparaciones y la consulta mencionada anteriormente , **y así seguido con la iteración 2, 3, 4 etc.**

Lo ideal es que esas comparaciones no llenen la memoria RAM o se ponga lento el programa, ya que estoy trabajando con Django 4. por eso no he intentado realizar bucles `for`

Agradezco cualquier aporte que me ayude a solucionar este problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: Esto parece el típico caso de [problema X Y](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_XY)

Comment: qué pretendes obtener tras todas esas comparaciones? si hay elementos repetidos? si hay dos iguales seguidos? mejor explicas _para qué_ necesitas hacer eso, pues quizás no necesites hacerlo